# Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string ERROR

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to pass a value from my database to an input, but I throw the following error.I'm not sure if for this case you should use return $ this-> db-> get () -> row (); in the model. Any help is welcome.

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: 4096

Message: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Filename: usuarios/vConsulta_Horarios.php

Line Number: 590

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\SAE\application\views\usuarios\vConsulta_Horarios.php
Line: 590
Function: _error_handler

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\SAE\application\controllers\cCalendar.php
Line: 26
Function: view

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\SAE\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
```

Model (mCalendar)

```
public function lunes(){


$this->db->select('MIN(horario.hrs_ini)');
$this->db->from('horario');
$this->db->join('usuarios','horario.rut_usu = usuarios.rut_usu');
$this->db->where('usuarios.rut_usu','17811942-4'); 
$this->db->where('horario.lunes','ATTE. ESTUDIANTES');


return $this->db->get()->row();
```

Controller (cCalendar)

```
public function index(){


        $this->load->view('layouts/header.php');
        $this->load->view('layouts/menu.php');

        $this->load->model('mCalendar');
        $data['start_lunes'] = $this->mCalendar->lunes();
        $this->load->view('usuarios/vConsulta_Horarios.php',$data);
        $this->load->view('layouts/footer.php');

}
```

View

```
    <div class="col-md-2">

        <div class="form-group">
          <label>fecha</label>
          <input tupr="text" id="fecha_actual" name="fecha_actual" value="<?php echo $start_lunes;?>">
        </div>
     </div>
```

Comment: can you add the code of cCalendar.php?

Comment: is the controller

Comment: ah, sorry, my misread! What do you use to manage db? probably the result of "row()" is not a single value but an object

Comment: I should return this 17:30:00

Comment: will only return a result always

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `return $this->db->get()->row();` returns object you are getting this error
You need to refer [this link](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html)

So now, I will suggest you one thing to return data properly.
In your Controller change return `$this->db->get()->row();`

to

```
  return $this->db->get()->result_array();
```

Now you are getting data in the format of Array and you can echo this in your **View** using

// **In your view**

```
foreach($start_lunes as $var){
        $value = $var['MIN(horario.hrs_ini)'];
    }

<input type="text" id="fecha_actual" name="fecha_actual" value="<?php echo $value?>"
```

Comment: <input type="text" id="fecha_actual" name="fecha_actual" value="<?php foreach($start_lunes as $var){
    echo  $var['hrs_ini'];
}
} ?>"  ???

Comment: <?php foreach($start_lunes as $var){ 
 $value =  $var['hrs_ini'];
}
?>
<input type="text" id="fecha_actual" name="fecha_actual" value="<?php echo $value?>">

Comment: try to print_r($start_lunes);

Comment: tell me the result of that

Comment: Array ( [0] => Array ( [MIN(horario.hrs_ini)] => 15:30:00 ) )

Comment: public function lunes(){

    
    $this->db->select('MIN(horario.hrs_ini)');
    $this->db->from('horario');
    $this->db->join('usuarios','horario.rut_usu = usuarios.rut_usu');
    $this->db->where('usuarios.rut_usu','17811942-4'); 
    $this->db->where('horario.lunes','ATTE. ESTUDIANTES');
    return $this->db->get()->result_array();
  
    }

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: hrs_ini

Filename: usuarios/vConsulta_Horarios.php

Line Number: 590

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\SAE\application\views\usuarios\vConsulta_Horarios.php
Line: 590
Function: _error_handler

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\SAE\application\controllers\cCalendar.php
Line: 26
Function: view

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\SAE\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

Comment: $value = $var['MIN(horario.hrs_ini)']; //  edit with this code

Comment: I do not understand where I'm supposed to write that ...: C

Comment: I just edited my answer check out that and Go through the basics of Codeingniter refer: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/

Comment: It works ... though ... I just wanted to print the result, this was a test to see if it was possible. Since I needed to pass it to fullccalendar.

Comment: and with the foreach I do not allow it

Answer (score 1):

Even though you are only selecting one column, you still need to specify it when you output, because `$start_lunes` is the object that represents the entire row, and as the error tells you, it can't be converted to a string.

I think `echo $start_lunes->hrs_ini` should work.

---

Based on your updated function, I think it would be easier if you aliased the MIN expression in your select

```
$this->db->select('MIN(horario.hrs_ini) AS min_hrs');
```

Then refer to that in your view: `echo $start_lunes->min_hrs`

Comment: <input type="text" id="fecha_actual" name="fecha_actual" value="<?php echo $start_lunes->hrs_ini;?>">  it does not work :C

Comment: do var_dump($start_lunes); and let us know what's the output

Comment: How so? What does it do? Same error? Different error? Nothing?

Comment: $data['start_lunes'] = $this->mCalendar->lunes();
            var_dump($start_lunes);should it go this way? I've never used it

Comment: just add the var_dump() on top of the view's page... <?php print "<pre>"; var_dump($start_lunes); die(); ?>... this will show you the content of variable

Comment: I think your $start_lunes returning object as mentioned by @parpar you check it by using var_dump($start_lunes);die();

Comment: object(stdClass)#22 (1) {
  ["MIN(horario.hrs_ini)"]=>
  string(8) "15:30:00"
}

Comment: That's weird. It doesn't look like that query would do a MIN.

Comment: add MIN to SQL query XD

Comment: as suggested by @Don'tPanic, it should solve your issue

$this->db->select('MIN(horario.hrs_ini) AS min_hrs');

View:
echo $start_lunes->min_hrs